# How can i download and install ROS in windows

Tags: ros, windows, download

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am pretty new to ROS, from where can i download or buy ROS for my windows and how can i install it?
Please provide me direct links for downloads. thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/165341/how-can-i-download-and-install-ros-in-windows/) by [anvesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/18051/anvesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This page gives general directions on how to download and install ROS on windows: http://wiki.ros.org/win_ros

As far as I'm aware, there is no single executable or installer that you can download and run.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anvesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/18051/anvesh/) on 2014-05-15**:
Thank you for your answer, i have already been through that page so many times but i m still confused how to install it in my computer? is there any other easy way or steps to install ROS?

**Comment by [LikeSmith](https://answers.ros.org/users/18041/likesmith/) on 2014-05-15**:
ros is not supported on windows.  I would recommend using a virtual machine, such as virtualbox, that runs ubuntu and install ros there.

**Comment by [anvesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/18051/anvesh/) on 2014-05-15**:
Can you please tell me how to do it?

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2017-08-07**:
If you are running Windows 10, try this: http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can download virtualbox here: https://www.virtualbox.org You will want to download the ubuntu iso from their website ( [www.ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com) )  right now, you would probably want 12.04 as ROS Indigo isn't released yet.

http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-on-VirtualBox here is a tutorial on how to create a virtual machine and install ubuntu on it.  After you have installed ubuntu, go the the main ros website and follow the installation guide for ubuntu (it is much more straight forward than the windows instructions) and enjoy!

---

Originally posted by [LikeSmith](https://answers.ros.org/users/18041/likesmith/) with karma: 61 on 2014-05-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4